# Java keeps throwing UnkownHostException after plug pull

Tags: java

So, I was trying to build this custom connection pool with some retry mechanism. And when I was testing it, I pulled out the ethernet cable to test if the mechanism works after I put it back in. When I pulled it out, I got the `UnknownHostException` thrown. Expected. Then I put it back in and waited.. for a good 4-5 minutes, but I kept getting the exception.

By this time there was a lot of code written, so I thought maybe the bug is down somewhere there, so just to rule out, I wrote the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    while (true) {
        try {
            new URL("https://www.google.com").openStream();
            System.out.println("Got Data");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Thread.sleep(2000);
    }
}
```

And the exact same thing happened. I keep on getting an `UnknownHostException` no matter what, even after I plug the cable back in. All other network applications, the browser and stuff works fine. Ideas?

Comment: You should close your streams.

Comment: Take a look at the Java Networking properties - Java caches DNS info - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/properties.html

Comment: There is indeed dns caching but not more than 30 seconds - http://javaeesupportpatterns.blogspot.de/2011/03/java-dns-cache-reference-guide.html and the `.negative.ttl` which should apply here because it fails to resolve defaults to only 10 seconds. You (or a security manager) can alter those values but I doubt that's the problem.

Comment: @shmosel This was just some test code I wrote to verify what I was seeing.